# add vertex to an edge in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode

When I want to add a vertex to an edge in *Edit Mode* at first it works, but when I want to add two other vertices it messes it up.

The following images will make you understand more[image]

Answer (score 1):

Click each edge to which you want to add vertices and simply click "Subdivide" in the right-click menu.

To move the vertices to where you want them, hit [G,G], which will let you slide the vertexes along the edge.

Answer (score 0):

You can only create new edge loop through quads: quads have an opposite edge, tris or ngons haven't, Blender can't guess how it is supposed to cut off a tri or a ngon:

[image]